# Alguém pode me ajudar a entender essa linha de código em javasript?

Tags: javascript, lógica

Este algortitmo é implementado num projeto do livro *Use a cabeça! Programação em Javascript*, do **capitulo 8** *criado um batalha naval*. 

 Onde não consegui entender esse trecho de código.

```
   if(hit && model.shipsSunk === model.numShips){
      view.displayMessage("you sank all my battkeships, in" + this.guesses + " guesses")
    }
```

> hit:É uma variavel que  possui um valor  true ou false que é retornado de  uma função.
>
> model.shipsSunk: é uma propriedade de um objeto, ele possui um valor Number e ele vai sendo incrementado por outros métodos durante  execução do código.
>
> model.numShips: possui um valor Number e ele e uma constante, também é uma propriedade do mesmo objeto que shipsSunk faz parte.
>
> **Não entendi a lógica do if**
> em comparar hit que  é um booleano, ShipsSunk e numShips que são Number.
> sei que usamos && para valores Booleanos, && retorna verdadeiro se ambos os operandos forem verdadeiro ; senão, retorna falso.
> No caso se hit receber um valor **True** como o operador lógico **&&** vai me retornar um valor booleano se shipShunk é um number e ainda comparar se é igual à numShips ? 
> no livro explicar que:
> -Se o **hit** for **true** e **shipSunk for igual a numShips** aparecerá a mensagem do *view.displayMessage(...)* na tela.
> mas não consegui entender a lógica de como a condicional if vai fazer isso.

Comment: `model.shipsSunk === model.numShips` é true se os números forem iguais, e false se forem diferentes. Portanto você tem a operação `&&` entre dois booleanos. Ficou mais claro?

Answer (score -3):

O operador && retorna verdadeiro somente se as variáveis informadas forem as duas verdadeiras. Então, ele compara se o hit e os navios afundados são verdadeiros e depois compara com o numero de navios. Se tudo for satisfeito , sua mensagem será impressa na tela